# How to sort tabular view - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to sort a tabular view in IOS apps (Ascending, Descending). For that do we need to write our own sorting logics or any predefined methods are available in IOS?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own... at best you can sort the NSArray first and then use it in tableView's delegate methods like cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

so it will be sorted automatically ...

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `NSArray` as your data source you can sort it by calling:

```
myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```